# Creating a Node.js server that will result in a browser page that creates a sorted list of 25 states with their capitals

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code so far BUT I would like to make it look more sophisticated or at least styled. How can I at least list the array vertically?

```
var http = require('http');

statescaps = new Array("Alabama,Montgomery","Alaska,Juneau","Arizona,Phoenix","Arkansas,Little Rock","California,Sacramento","Colorado,Denver","Connecticut,Hartford","Delaware,Dover","Florida,Tallahassee","Georgia,Atlanta","Hawaii,Honolulu","Idaho,Boise","Illinois,Springfield","Indiana,Indianapolis","Iowa,Des Moines","Kansas,Topeka","Kentucky,Frankfort","Louisiana,Baton Rouge","Maine,Augusta","Maryland,Annapolis","Massachusetts,Boston","Michigan,Lansing","Minnesota,St. Paul","Mississippi,Jackson","Missouri,Jefferson City").sort()

http.createServer(function (req,res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.write("here are 25 US States and their Capitals:" + statescaps);
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list the states vertically, you can join the array using newline characters:

```
res.write("here are 25 US States and their Capitals:\n" + statescaps.join('\n');
```